# SQL ecommerce database. how to relate foreign keys in same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a sql table for orders. We have another table what has a primnary key of productID. When a customer creates an order it should list the orderID as well total and a foreignkey of productID. The issue I have is that it only allows 1 productID.

Is there a way for sql to add multiple foreign keys to the same row for the same item? If that makes sense?

I placed both tables here to try and show what I meant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take at a look at a well-designed sample database like Microsoft's [AdventureWorks](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks). Typically there is a parent-child table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure only allows one product per order, because you've got a single productId column on the orders table.

To allow multiple products per order, I would create an orderItems table. Each orderItem has a different productId, and links back to the orders table via an orderId. Like this:

```
------------------------
orders table
------------------------
orderId (primary key)
orderDate
orderTotal
customerId (foreign key)
specialInstructions

-------------------------
orderItems table
-------------------------
orderItemId (primary key)
orderId (foreign key)
productId (foreign key)
quantity

-------------------------
products table
-------------------------
productId (primary key)
productTitle
productDescription
productPrice
```